# Name of output wont work

Tags: batch-file

So tell me why this wont work..

```
set /p Name=Enter Name here: 
echo ^<Object id="%Name%"^> >> %Output%\Weapons\^%Name%.xml
```

I want the output xml file to be named after what i named the object id.
But the problem is that when i put something without spaces it works, but if i put a name with spaces the file will creates just the first part of the name for example "dagger of derp" it will name it "dagger" and if i look in the file it creates it will say
    (<)Object id="%name%">  asd.xml
and it wont be a xml file it will just be a "file"

Answer (score 1):

You have one caret to much and I miss double quotes:

```
echo ^<Object id="%Name%"^>>>"%Output%\Weapons\%Name%.xml"
```